# jquery selection of preselected item

Tags: jquery

I want selecting last option that appended in following code:

```
var o=$('select[name="D1"]');
o.append('<option value="'+buval+'">'+butxt+'</option>');
$("select[name="D1"] :last-child").fadeIn('slow')
```

I want choose it without select[name="D1"] in last code, because I had choosed it before. Is there any alternatives? like as following code?

```
 o.$(":last-child").fadeIn('slow')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
o.find(":last-child").fadeIn("slow");
```

Or:

```
$(":last-child", o).fadeIn("slow);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
o.children('option:last-child').fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: This would work if he were selecting `selects` that *were* last children, but there's a space in-between `select` and `:last-child` which means he's looking for last-child *descendants* of that select.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for acute observation